# Liferay JSP is redirecting me to a page i dont want to be redirect

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am developing liferay portlet. The portlet is pretty much done but i have big issue with the jsp redirection. Every time a query is successful it redirects not to the jsp i want but to my home jsp page.

The question is how can I make it to redirect me to a jsp page I want?

I am using liferay SDK for eclipse, Tomcat 7 and up to date Liferay

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What framework are you using in your portlet? MVCPortlet?

Comment: MVCPortlet i think because my java life is extending MVCPortlet class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it seems that you want to redirect to jsp from your controller

Use this :-

```
response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "jsppath");
```

Let me know if you have any problem !!!

Comment: If you're using Liferay 6.1, you should pass the "mvcPath" parameter instead: the "jspPage" name is deprecated.

Comment: @JohnRambo can you say me whats wrong in my answer? as you undo your answer selection

Comment: the browser is wrong i have no idea but i cannot accept any answers any more. i will change the browser an try again

Answer (score 0):

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/jsp/b.jsp");
```